# How can I copy page content for meta description and limit to 150 characters with php or js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, metadata

Previously, my website was only a few pages with each page having several tabs holding the individual articles. Because of this, my meta descriptions were simple and broad for each page to cover all the content.

However, I recently separated the articles to be on separate pages to help my SEO. As a result, I now have 174 pages with basically the same description. Obviously, this is bad for SEO and CTR.

Each article is on a separate text document stored several directories deep inside a template folder in the root directory.

I've tried several file functions to read and echo the contents of the file but I've only gotten it to work when the text file called for is in the same directory as the script.

So I thought of scraping the article from the current page and using that instead of using an external file. I tried the same file functions using the current page and it didn't work, I just got the head content to show and no body content.

My question is really 2 questions:
**1.)** How can I echo the contents of a file in a different directory and limit it to 150 characters with, preferably with php?
**2.)** If the above doesn't work or isn't possible, how can I do the same using the content of the script the code is located on with php, or js? I can change the divs containing the articles to have an id.

I'm looking for a code that is the exact same no matter the page it's on so I can bulk search/replace rather than edit 174 pages.

Note: I also tried using superglobals in my experiments specifically to make the code the same like I want. Also, I don't know js so please provide explanation or the full code snippet for any answers with js.

File structure:

```
root
!
!-tpl
! !
! !-articles
!   !
!   !-topic1
!     !
!     !-article1.txt
!-topic
! !
! !-topic1
!   !
!   !-page1.php
```

Article1.txt = Several paragraphs of content with p tags
Page1.php desired effect =

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta id="desc" name="Description" content="Copy of first 150 chars of article1.txt">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid article" id="article">
<?include "article1.txt"?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I've tried several file functions to read and echo the contents of the file but I've only gotten it to work when the text file called for is in the same directory as the script.` maybe you can share what you did here and we will help you? If you want to do it with a PHP perspective then ideally you can use a header which is included in each file

Comment: I'm using w3schools.com as my reference and one of the file functions I've been trying as far as using the current script's content is `file_get_contents` because it says `file_get_contents(path,include_path,context,start,max_length)` so I have both details that I need which is to read and echo the content and also limit the length. I found it works with a URL as well which is perfect because I can use superglobals. However, when I specify to start at 56588(the number of chars till the start of the article), it doesn't work. If I do 5000 or so, I only get the <head> content

Comment: With 56588, I get this error:
`file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking`

My code is like so:
`<?echo file_get_contents($full_url_to_page,1,0,NULL,56588);?>`

Comment: I think one simple way would be to use bash to edit the files. Are you using a Linux Based OS?

Comment: Ummm yes? If Linux and Unix are interchangeable then yes. It's not windows or anything. I use cPanel with my host. I have a bulk search/replace program on my pc, I can download the necessary files and then upload the edits. I just need to get the code right and preferably a universal code

Comment: Ohk, do you have a dedicated server or a shared cloud? Can you also edit your question to reflect the exact file structure and an example file with contents?

Comment: @KaranShah Added file structure

Comment: can you please also add a sample file and a sample output file? I will help you write a shell script for the same

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. Like an example of the code I'm trying to use and an example of where it would be in the webpage?

Comment: can you please let me know what's inside article.txt and what's in page1.php and what is the intended result

Comment: @KaranShah Done

Comment: one last request, can you please let me know how other files are stored in the directory structure

Comment: What files? The structure is the same for the articles and public pages, just different filenames. Like `tpl>articles>topic1>` holds text files 1-*, topic2 the same. `topic>topic1` holds php files named after the title of the article the file contains, likewise with topic2. That's pretty much all I'm working with, excluding the hundreds of other templates but they're not related to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a program for you assuming the current variables you provided me. Store this at the root level and run it

```
for file in `find . -type f -name article*.txt`
do
  filename=`echo $file | cut -d"/" -f 5`
  filename_no_ext=${filename%".txt"}
  number_of_file=${filename_no_ext#"article"}
  output_file_name=./topic/topic$number_of_file/page$number_of_file.php
  awk '{
    printf "\<\!DOCTYPE html\>\n\<head\>\n"
    printf "\<meta id=\"desc\" name=\"Description\" content=\"" substr($0,0,50)
    printf "\"\>\n\</head\>\n\<body\>\n"
    printf "\<div class=\"container-fluid article\" id=\"article\"\>\n"
    printf "\<\?include \"" FILENAME "\"\?\>\n"
    printf "\<\/div\>\n\</body\>\n\</html\>"
  }' $file > $output_file_name
done
```

Hope it helps, hope you can make minor modifications according to your needs

Comment: One place I have kept 50 in substr, make it 150 for the 150 char. Let me know if you're stuck somewhere